# #SQl#Number within Number

Tags: sql, case

I am looking to execute below statement and get number as 1,2...10 when score is between 1-10,11-20 .. but when i am executing , i am getting null..
between is not working any suggestion in this ?

```
          select   a.score  ,
                        CASE

          WHEN stg2.Stats = 'Existing'

          THEN
             CASE
             WHEN a.SCORE BETWEEN 1 AND 10 THEN 1
             WHEN a.SCORE BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN 2
                ..
                ..
                ..
                ...

               WHEN a.SCORE BETWEEN 81 AND 90 THEN 9
                WHEN a.SCORE BETWEEN 91 AND 100 THEN 10
             END
          ELSE
             NULL
       END
          score_num  

          FROM t1 stg2 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN t2  a
          ON     t1.KEY = t2.ACCNT_NUM
```

Comment: Do you have values between 1 and 100 in `Score` column and `Stats = 'Existing'` and common values between `t1.KEY = t2.ACCNT_NUM`

Comment: @juergend That would depend on `SCORE` being an `INT`

Comment: @Lamak: Right. Which it looks like.

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs , its working now .

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce your inner `case` statement to simply

```
(a.SCORE + 9) / 10
```